# Why is the normal distribution used in linear models, but in generalized linear models the exponential distribution is used?

Tags: regression, distributions, generalized-linear-model

Why is the normal distribution used in linear models, but in generalized linear models (GLMs) the exponential distribution is used?

Answer (score 17):

In GLM's the exponential family of distributions (not the exponential distribution, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) is used to model various outcomes, Gaussian (or normal) distribution for a real continuous variable, Gamma distribution for a real positive continuous variable, binomial distribution for a discrete variable, and so on.

An ordinary linear model is just one among the selection of distributions, which uses the normal distribution.

Answer (score 11):

An ordinary linear model -- which uses the normal distribution -- is just one GLM used for one purpose; other purposes suggest other distributions.
Not all generalised linear models (GLMs) use an exponential distribution.

Terminology is also confusing: "Exponential distribution" in the context of a statement like 'Generalised Linear Models use exponential distributions' means "[one of the *Exponential **family*** of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), not "[the *exponential* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

GLMs [use one of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Model_components) the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) of distributions to model various outcomes:

| Use | Domain | Variable | Distribution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| linear response | all reals | continuous | Gaussian (normal) |
| scale parameter | positive reals | continuous | Gamma |
| Binary outcome count | integers | discrete | Binomial |

... and so on; see the [GLM link function table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function) on Wikipedia, for example.